Regarding a limit in the context of the hypergeometric equation's monodromy
I'm working on the final part of this paper, more specifically in the calculation of the last matrix, this being
\begin{gather*}
  \begin{bmatrix}%
    \lambda_{\beta} & \lambda_{\beta'}\\
    \lambda'_{\beta} & \lambda'_{\beta'}
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \phi(a,\,c-b,\,c) & \phi(b,\,c-a,\,c)\\
    e^{\pi\,i(1-c)}\phi(a-c+1,\,1-b,\,2-c) & e^{\pi\,i(1-c)}\phi(b-c+1,\,1-a,\,2-c)
  \end{bmatrix}
  .
\end{gather*}
Note that $$  \phi(a,\,b,\,c):={}_2F_1
            \left(
            \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
              a,\,b \\
              c
            \end{array}
            \,\middle|\,
            1 \right)
            =\frac{\Gamma(c)\,\Gamma(c-a-b)}{\Gamma(c-a)\,\Gamma(c-b)}.
$$
To compute this matrix I'm using the following solutions, of the 24 Kummer solutions listed in the paper (pages 20-21),

$P^{(\alpha)}={}_3w_1(z)=(1-z)^{-a}{}_2F_1
            \left(
            \begin{array}
              aa,\,c-b \\
              c
            \end{array}
            \,\middle|\,
            \frac{z}{z-1} \right)$,
$P^{(\alpha')}={}_3w_2(z)=z^{1-c}(1-z)^{-(a-c+1)}{}_2F_1
            \left(
            \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
              a-c+1,\,1-b \\
              2-c
            \end{array}
            \,\middle|\,
            \frac{z}{z-1} \right)\\$,
$P^{(\beta)}={}_3w_5(z)=(-z)^{-a}\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)^{-a}{}_2F_1
            \left(
            \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
              a,\,c-b \\
              a-b+1
            \end{array}
            \,\middle|\,
            \frac{1}{1-z} \right)\\$,
$P^{(\beta')}={}_3w_6(z)=(-z)^{-b}\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)^{-b}{}_2F_1
            \left(
            \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
              b,\,c-a \\
              b-a+1
            \end{array}
            \,\middle|\,
            \frac{1}{1-z} \right).$

With this in mind, we have that, when $z\to\infty$,
$$P^{(\alpha)}\sim(1-z)^{-a}\phi(a,c-b,c),$$
$$P^{(\alpha)}\sim z^{1-c}(1-z)^{-(a-c+1)}\phi(a-c+1,1-b,2-c),$$
$$P^{(\beta)}\sim (1-z)^{-a},$$
$$P^{(\beta')}\sim (1-z)^{-b}.$$
Anyway, my idea is that either one of the last two has limit 0 (when $z\to\infty$); the only thing we know (as far as I understand) about $a,\,b$ is that $$\Re(c-a-b)>0,$$
this is so that we can define our $\phi$ (as far as I can tell). So we have now different cases, if $\Re c>0$ then we're good because then either the real parts of $a$ or $b$ have to be negative and so the limit is 0. However the issue arises when $\Re c<0$, in this case then it may as well happen that neither $a$ nor $b$ have negative real parts and so the limit is $\infty$.
A needed observation, $a,b,c$ are reparametrizations of the exponents of the singular regular points (see page 11 right at the beginning).
